# Jsoup: Unable to retrieve time/date elements

Tags: java, css, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to extract some data from the following link and I can retrieve contents of any element of that page except the one that holds a dynamic time. I tried every possible CSS Selectors and none of them worked. You might want to inspect the element [of this page](http://bikroy.com/en/ads-in-bangladesh?query=Nokia&category=&location=).

### HTML:

```
    <div class="meta">
        <span class="information-row properties"></span>
        <span class="information-row">
            <span class="date" data-time="1414176068">

                Today 12:41 am <!-- This is the text I want to extract -->

            </span>

            ,


            <span class="category"></span>

            ,


            <span class="location"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

### The Java Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://bikroy.com/en/ads-in-bangladesh?query=Nokia&category=&location=").userAgent("Chrome").timeout(999999).get();

            Elements titles = doc.select("div.title");
            Elements prices = doc.select("span.data");
            Elements locations = doc.select("span.location");
            Elements dates = doc.select("span.date");
            //Elements dates = doc.select("[data-time*=14]");

            for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {
                  System.out.println("\nTitle: " + titles.get(i).text() + "\nPrice: " +  prices.get(i).text() + "\nLocation: " +  locations.get(i).text() + "\nDate: " +  dates.get(i).text());
            }


   }
}
```

### Sample Output:

```
Title: Brand New Nokia Lumia 530 Dual Sim
Price: Tk. 8,000
Location: Dhaka
Date: 

Title: Nokia n95
Price: Tk. 999
Location: Dhaka
Date: 

Title: Nokia c3-01
Price: Tk. 3,500
Location: Dhaka
Date:
```

See? The Date is empty!! How can I fix this?

**Update:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

            Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://bikroy.com/en/ads-in-bangladesh?query=Nokia&category=&location=").userAgent("Chrome").timeout(999999).get();

            Elements titles = doc.select("div.title");
            Elements prices = doc.select("span.data");
            Elements locations = doc.select("span.location");
            Elements dates = doc.select("span.date");

            int j = 0;
            String[] d = new String[dates.size()];
            for(Element date:dates){
                d[j++] = date.attr("data-time");
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++) {

                long unixSeconds = Long.valueOf(d[i]).longValue();
                Date dt = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6"));
                String fd = sdf.format(dt);

                 System.out.println("\nTitle: " + titles.get(i).text() + "\nPrice: " +  prices.get(i).text() + "\nLocation: " +  locations.get(i).text() + "\nPosted On: " + fd);
            }


   }
}
```

**New output:**

```
Title: Nokia C5-00
Price: Tk. 2,850
Location: Dhaka Division
Posted On: 26-Oct-2014 11:46:39 PM

Title: Nokia lumia 1320
Price: Negotiable price
Location: Dhaka
Posted On: 26-Oct-2014 11:39:13 PM

Title: Nokia N73
Price: Tk. 1,000
Location: Dhaka
Posted On: 26-Oct-2014 11:37:14 PM
```

Comment: (A) I wonder if the word `date` in particular is causing a problem. Just a hunch. Try creating a sample of data with a different word like `elephant` or `abc`. (B) That `data-time` attribute should be your target. It is the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, beginning of 1970 in UTC, as you can [see here](http://www.epochconverter.com/). Search StackOverflow to learn how to convert that number to a date-time object. Example using Joda-Time 2.5 library: `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 1414176068L * 1000L , DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );`

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for your reply. I admit that the word date is really creating confusion here and I should've focused on **time** instead. Simply put, displaying the **time of each ad** (it's an ebay-like site) is what I really want.

I didn't know about the _Epoch Conversion_ and _Joda Time library_ until now. Thank u for letting me know. Is it possible to manipulate time in these formats: "xx seconds ago", "xx minutes ago", "Today XX:XX AM" etc. using Joda-Time?

Just curious, why is jsoup failing to parse that `span.date`?

Comment: Your code should work. I suspect you found a bug. Please devise some dummy data and a short example app to prove if it is a bug. If you can prove it, submit that as a bug report to the jsoup project. After that, search StackOverflow for "joda" or "java date" to find much discussion and example code for working with date-time values. In particular look for "Period" and "PeriodFormatter" classes in Joda-Time to represent a span of time.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thread updated. I converted the timestamp. I'll now look into PeriodFormatter. Thanks again for your suggestions.

And it wasn't a bug. I just forgot to check the raw html of that page. As @fonkap mentioned below, content of `span class="date"` is hidden in the page source. Jsoup won't be able to parse it. It can only be seen using Inspect Element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the raw html of the page, the `span class="date"` doesn't have contents, the page must be picking the `data-time` attribute and converting it with javascript.

I think you have to do the same. Read data-time and convert to Date.

Hint: date-time looks as a timestamp in seconds.